# Username and Password field not showing

Tags: html, css

If you look at the image, it doesn't show the boxes where you can input the username and password. It's blended in with the background (I can still input text into the fields).

Does anyone know what is happening here?

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKRbJ.png)

Comment: Please share the CSS. You might have disabled borders.

Comment: Please post your code. We cannot troubleshoot an image.

Comment: I think OP saw this and is wondering how it's achieved, he didnt create it himself. This is styled with css where the border is taken off

Comment: @duxfox-- Yes! Thank you so much! All you have to do is take the borders off.

Comment: Starting web programming today; better late than never. ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how you can do that:

```
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/cjvacv33/2/